# Capybara with js driver not logging in

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am using the following rspec setup code:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

But nontheless it still doesn't work. My JS tests are failing with trivial things and oddly. It'll pass the first round, and then when it runs again it won't pass. It'll complain couldn't `find model with id` the next time it runs. This is with guard-rspec.

Comment: Where and how do you add your objects to the database?

Comment: Here is the code, the commented out code is what breaks. https://gist.github.com/ecl1pse/4bd64f4ee3cccfcfed59